# Give up on someone in Italian

Tags: phrase-request

I am wondering what the most accurate translation of the English phrase "to give up on someone" is in Italian. I am aware that there may be multiple, depending on the context, so I would just ask you to translate a few sentences:

"I thought he was a worthy student, but in the end I just gave up on him."

"He never gave up on me, even when I was treating him really badly."

"Thank you for not giving up on me when I failed"

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE! Unfortunately this is not a translation service site, but if can you  show us your best attempt along with your doubts I think someone on this site will be pleased to help you.

Comment: The only reason I am asking for translations is so that I have a full understanding of the issue. I do not need any of these sentences in particular, I would just like to know how to express this concept (which I don't).

Comment: My dictionary says that “give up on” means “stop having faith or belief in”. In Italian it could be “perdere la fiducia”.

Comment: https://www.wordreference.com/enit/give%20up suggests "give up on sb => (1) lasciare, lasciare perdere, abbandonare (2) perdere la fiducia in". Meaning 2 seems spot-on here.

Answer (score 4):

I generally translate it with "lasciar perdere" or "rinunciare". With this in mind, your phrases would translate in:

"Pensavo fosse uno studente meritevole, ma ho finito con il lasciarlo perdere".

"Non si è mai arreso con me, anche quando lo stavo trattando veramente male".

"Grazie per non esserti arreso con me quando ho fallito".